# Can an anonymous class implement the non abstract method of the abstract class?

Tags: java, findbugs

Can an Abstract class non abstract method be overridden by using Anonymous class?. The FindBugs tool is issuing " Uncallable method of anonymous class" issue. Please check the below example for more information

```
public class BaseClass {
    // This class is a Library Class.
}

public abstract class AbstractBaseClass extends BaseClass {
    public abstract void abstractMethod();
    public void nonAbstractMethod() {}
}

public abstract class DerivedAbstractClass extends AbstractBaseClass {
   // Here Some more additional methods has been added
}

public class DemoAbstract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        DerivedAbstractClass derivedAbstractClass = new DerivedAbstractClass() {
            @Override
            public void abstractMethod() {

            }

            @Override
            public void nonAbstractMethod() {
                 // Is it possible to override like this?
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Does that exact example (copied and pasted, no changes at all) generate the warning?

Comment: Of course you can override it, but even if you don't, the anonymous class still provides an implementation, so a better question would be: can an anonymous class not implement this method ?

Comment: Hello immibis, I have edited my example. Please check the exact example which I am following.

Comment: I don't see the problem sorry, this is used a lot defining listeners (for example in Android the View.OnClickListener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. 
You can override any non final, non static method

Comment: Can't I override `main()` in JAVA? It is static but I can !!

Comment: But, For the above code the FindBugs has reported a bug saying that: This anonymous class defined a method that is not directly invoked and does not override a method in a superclass. [From FindBugs™ description](http://10.36.18.158:50000/docs/en/findbugs/fb_checker_ref.html#FB.UMAC_UNCALLABLE_METHOD_OF_ANONYMOUS_CLASS)

Comment: @Junaid no, you can't.

Comment: @SarathUpadrista: I don't see any problems in the code provided. Can you post the content of `DerivedAbstractClass`?

Comment: I would like to know what exactly meant by 'UNCALLABLE_METHOD_OF_ANONYMOUS_CLASS' which has been reported by 'FindBugs'. How can an overridden method be UnCallable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible!

Reason?

Anonymous class enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time, and in your sample code this is the line: (`DerivedAbstractClass derivedAbstractClass = new DerivedAbstractClass()`).

Anonymous Classes are like local classes except that they do not have a name.

In the snipped below, you are extending DerivedAbstractClass and can provide implementations for its abstract methods, and if you want, you may also override non-abstract method too.

But you may want to call `super.nonAbstractMethod();` before overriding if required, as below:

```
 DerivedAbstractClass derivedAbstractClass = new DerivedAbstractClass() {
                @Override
                public void abstractMethod() {
                //anonymous clas providing implemntation

                }

                @Override
                public void nonAbstractMethod() {
                super.nonAbstractMethod();
                //anonymous clas overriding      
                }
            };
```